# How to use Serverless VPC access for Cloud functions

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I have created a Kubernetes clusters with sample Spring Boot application and it works well from public ip. Now I want to access the end point of Spring boot in Kubernetes clusters. I have already followed the tutorial from Google for Configuring Serverless VPC Access. (https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access?hl=bg). I have created the Serverless VPC access and used in one of cloud function.

Now my problem is, how can I connect the internal ip of Kubernetes clusters from my cloud function?. I have written code in Go.

```html
package p

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Starting the application...")

    response, err := http.Get("http://10.59.247.177:47002/")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "The HTTP request failed with error %s\n", err)
    } else {
        data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        fmt.Fprint(w, string(data))
    }
}
```

But I am getting error: The HTTP request failed with error %s
Get http://10.59.247.177:47002/: dial tcp 10.59.247.177:47002: i/o timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Kubernetes services are internal to Kubernetes cluster. You have to expose services so that applications from outside of Kubernetes can connect to it.

There are 3 main ways to expose service in Kubernetes:

1. Public load balancer. Service is exposed to Internet.
2. Internal load balancer. Service is exposed internally within VPC and region.
3. NodePort. Service is exposed on Kube nodes IP addresses on some high number port. This makes service visible internally and between regions within VPC.

Read more here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types and here https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. Actually, I have already setup the public load balancer, which works fine. I tried that public IP in the cloud function. It works too. I will try the internal load balancer.

Comment: I read in your profile that you work with openstack. how can i use openstack as loadbalancer for kubernetes?
do you use magnum or ZUN?

my openstack is too slow what should i do?
excuseme to ask it here but it is important to me.I am be glad to have your email. could you please add it in your profile?

Comment: I followed the guideline for creating internal load balance. (https://cloud.google.com/files/internal-load-balancing-tutorial-slides.pdf). But my load balancer always unhealthy. How can I create correct one and connect in the cloud function? There are no other guides or tutorials available

Comment: You should follow these steps: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing